# PHP / MySQL: How to modify working Select when the result is always one row

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am new to PHP and MySQL and am looking for some help with the following.

Usually when I need to fetch data from the db and I know the result will be more than one row than I fetch the data and store it an array as below for further use in PHP which **works as intended**:

```
$sql = "SELECT " . $selectedLang . ", tID, info FROM TranslationsMain WHERE location LIKE '%language main%' ORDER BY " . $selectedLang;
$result = $conn->query($sql);  
while($arrLanguagesMain = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $languagesMain[] = $arrLanguagesMain;
}
```

**Now I have a scenario where the result will always be just one row**. 
Currently I use the following query for this but in this case I don't need an array (this returns e.g. "`Array ( [en] => English )`" ).
Here **I simply need it to return the value** from the column `$selectedLang` which in this example would be "`English`".

```
$sql = "SELECT " . $selectedLang . " FROM TranslationsMain WHERE info = '" . $selectedLang . "'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);  
while($arrSelectedTrans = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $selectedTrans = $arrSelectedTrans;
}
```

Can someone tell me what is the best / preferred approach to modify the above so that it returns a single value instead of creating an array ?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just get the value of that array by its index:

```
$sql = "SELECT " . $selectedLang . " FROM TranslationsMain WHERE info = '" . $selectedLang . "'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);  
while($arrSelectedTrans = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $selectedTrans = $arrSelectedTrans[$selectedLang];
    //you can use break; here to make sure it runs only once
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using

> [fetch_object()](http://php.net/manual/ro/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php)

```
$sql = "SELECT " . $selectedLang . " FROM TranslationsMain WHERE info = '" . $selectedLang . "'";
$selectedTrans = $conn->query($sql)->fetch_object()->$selectedLang;
```

Comment: Thanks for that - I found a way that works for me here (see below).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way that works best for me here:

**To select the single row:**

```
$sql = "SELECT " . $selectedLang . " FROM TranslationsMain WHERE info = '" . $selectedLang . "' LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);  
$selectedTrans = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

**...and to echo it somewhere on the page:**

```
echo $selectedTrans[$selectedLang];
```

Thanks anyways for the help.